# Authentication credentials weere not provided when signing up

Tags: python, django

Building Django APIs to help me handle both the signup and login process for my React app.

I am able to successfully login (get an access and refresh token from Django upon login), but having difficulties connecting my React signup process to Django to create a new user.

This is the error I am getting on my console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ 401 (Unauthorized)
onSubmit @ Signup.js:32
```

and on my network:

```
Authentication credentials were not provided.
```

This is what I have in my serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only':True},
        }
        def create(self,validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'],
                                            password=validated_data['password'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'])
            return user

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)


class PasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

accounts.urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('signup.urls')),
]
```

signup.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView)
from .api import RegisterApi

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path('api/register', RegisterApi.as_view()),
]
```

and finally signup.views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework import permissions
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer, PasswordSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    #changed name from UserSerializer to RegisterSerializer
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.validated_data['new_password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is my api.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, mixins
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer, UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

#Register API
class RegisterApi(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user,    context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "message": "User Created Successfully.  Now perform Login to get your token",
        })
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self == 'create':
            return [AllowAny()]
        else:
            return super().get_permissions()

    def get_authenticators(self):
        if self == 'create':
            return []
        else:
            return super().get_authenticators()
```

I am posting to this URL in the signup process:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register'
```

Comment: Did you happen to [set `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined) or [`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) in your django project `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings? If so, then all your endpoints, even user creation, require authentication by default.

Comment: @sytech default authentication classes are:         'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'

I'm guessing a signup would not ideally require authentication?

Comment: @sytech I also have         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
 in Default_PERMISSION_CLASSES

Comment: Whether your signup should require authentication is dependent on your application's requirements. I added an answer below that hopefully will work for you. You might also want to explore additional options like [email based authentication](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-authemail/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you have a default authentication/permission scheme which applies to all your views. However, your signup process (perhaps understandably) is not authenticated, since there is not user account to authorize at this point.

One way to get around this would be to allow anonymous signup by not requiring permissions to create a user, assuming that is a desired behavior for your app.

You can do this by [overriding `get_permissions`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions) on the ViewSet, making the required permission classes to be `AllowAny` only when the viewset action is `create`.

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def get_permissions(self):
        """
        dont require permissions for create actions
        otherwise, follow normal required permissions
        """
        if self.action == 'create':
            return [AllowAny()]
        else:
            return super().get_permissions()
```

Alternatively, you can develop an authentication/authorization mechanism for creating new users. For example, you may choose to explore [email-based token authentication](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-authemail/) for your user signup process.

You may also need to override `get_authenticators(self)`:

```py
...
    def get_authenticators(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return []
        else:
            return super().get_authenticators()
```

Comment: Thanks. Still getting the same error message even after trying this

Comment: @Emm Hmm. Is your request sending any authorization header or authentication information? If a request attempts to send authentication information (even if `AllowAny` is used) then authentication will fail.

Comment: I'm only sending a username, password and an email

Comment: @Emm hmm. I didn't think it would be needed, but you may also need to override `get_authenticators`. updated the answer. Let me know if that works. But it really shouldn't be needed if no authentication is being attempted -- I would double check the request headers being used to make certain no authentication is being sent.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: @Emm are you sure you're applying this to the correct viewset? I may have used the wrong one in the answer. It looks like your urls.py point to `RegisterApi` for the `api/register` endpoint not `UserViewSet`. So try applying the change to that view if you haven't already. Otherwise, I'm not sure what might be causing that.

Comment: Tried it on RegisterAPi getting the error: 'RegisterApi' object has no attribute 'action'